# Visual Force Pages and Debug Logs

Tags: visualforce, controller

I have Created the Visualforce Page and apex class which Means Controller Class
to count the Viewers of users using the Visualforce Page

VisualForce Page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showheader="false" StandardController="Page_View__c" extensions="DisplayPage" action="{!TotalRecordUpdate}">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:form />
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            title="your record details of ID:{!CurrentRecordID}"
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:outputField value="{!Page_View__c.Count__c}" />
</apex:page>
```

Apex class:

```
public class DisplayPage {
    public string CurrentRecordID {get;set;}
    public  list<Page_View__c> viewList {get;set;}
    public static string CurrentRecordID1 {get;set;}
    public DisplayPage(ApexPages.StandardController Controller) {
        CurrentRecordID = ApexPages.currentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        system.debug(CurrentRecordID);
        viewList = [select id, Count__c from    Page_View__c where id =: CurrentRecordID];
        system.debug(viewList);
        DisplayPage.TotalRecordUpdate();
    }
    public static void TotalRecordUpdate() {
        CurrentRecordID1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        List <  Page_View__c > totalupdate = new List < Page_View__c > ();
        List <  Page_View__c > recDetails = [select id, Count__c from   Page_View__c where id =: CurrentRecordID1];
        for (   Page_View__c updateCount: recDetails)
        {
            updateCount.Count__c = updateCount.Count__c++;
            totalUpdate.add(updateCount);
        }
        update totalUpdate;
    }
}
```

I am getting the Debug Log  of currentRecordId is Null,How to Rectify the Error,How to get the Id Value in CurrentRecordid Anyone Guide Me for the Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the URL with which you are opening your Visualforce page? Does it have the `Id` parameter?

You need to add the `Id` to your URL, so that URL looks similar to this: 
`/apex/MyVFPage?Id=a4C90000000PIax`

Otherwise, the `ApexPages.currentPage().getparameters().get('id')` will return `NULL`

**UPDATE**

You can't call the `ApexPages.currentPage().getparameters().get('id')` inside the static method. Try passing the `Id` as a parameter to your `TotalRecordUpdate` function when calling it from constructor. You already have the `Id` in `CurrentRecordID` variable.

Comment: it is showing error like this:System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Class.DisplayPage.TotalRecordUpdate: line 18, column 1
Class.DisplayPage.<init>: line 10, column 1

Comment: How to Rectify the Error

Comment: @user36188 see my update

Comment: Now what i have to do @smukov

Comment: if i use Direct variable , it is not showing CurrentRecordId is Not exist  what i have to do

Comment: Hi @user36188, your original question has been answered and the `currentRecordId is Null` problem has been solved. Please, post a new question with your updated code so we can debug your new issue in a new thread. Thanks.